# Weird behavior. Parameter for date column in oracle db

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, frameworks

I am getting this weird behavior in Oracle12. I am using oracle.managed.dataAccess in VisualStudio 2019

Here is like, the situations:
I am using a parameter variable (which is by default a string) and I am getting no results. The statement itself works(no error), but I'm not getting any db entrys back, cause of the date parameter.
The date_column is type date in the db.

```c++
string sql = "select * from Table where c_id = :myC_id and date_column > to_date(:myDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')";

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = connectionstring;
cmd.CommadnText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("myC_id",myC_id)); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("myDate",myDate));
```

I tried the parameter as string, as date, as everything. Converted it back and forth, still not working. BUT, if I hardcode the date as string like below it is working. I am getting the results and data.

```
string sql = "select * from Table where c_id = :myC_id and date_column > to_date('2021-03-30 09:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')";
```

I am getting the data too, if I concatenate my string variable to the sql string like below.

```
string myDate = "'" + "2021-03-30 09:00:00" + "'";
string sql = "select * from Table where c_id = :myC_id and date_column > to_date({myDate}, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')";
```

But its not working with the parameter, can someone tell me why, and how I make it work?

Comment: I don't know tools you use, but this is certainly wrong. I guess/hope it is a typo: yyyy-mm-dd hh**23**:mi:ss

Comment: Assuming `to_date` parses a string date into a database date type, and that `myDate` in C# is a `DateTime`, why are you treating `:mydate` as a string in your first example? Is it not `date_column > :myDate`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a the C# code where you define the variables and assign them values.

Comment: Typo? `hh23` instead of `hh24`

Comment: Do you need to truncate the hours minutes and seconds?  Do you need >= instead of >?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, I typed it wrong, here in the question, it is hh24, NOT hh23, its edited

Comment: @Llama myDate in C# is a string, and it will be parsed  to db date type. I tried also a DateTime, I tried to_char in the sql I tried everything.

Comment: Please show your example using `DateTime`.

Comment: @Llama DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(myDate);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("myDate",OracleDbType.Date, myDate)); without the "to_date"

Comment: And on the SQL side? Also, did the date parse correctly into `dt`? (This is probably better as a general edit to your question...)

Comment: string sql = "select * from Table where c_id = :myC_id and date_column > :myDate " ; Yes the dt parse worked corrctly. But the statement throws an error with the DateTime, saying, it expects a number and got an date

Comment: Can you try (from C#) something like this (assuming Oracle has no issues with it): `SELECT :myDate AS date` as a query by itself and see what it spits out. Is it the value you expect? Anyway. I'm thinking this might be something Oracale-specific so I'm going to duck out since it not my area of expertise. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't right now, but I think, I know what u mean, so I will try it asap.

Comment: @MT0 the myDate ist just a string, so string myDate = "2021-03-30 09:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

The following Example should help you.

**Setup**

```
create table tableX (id number(10), c_id number(10), date_column date );

insert into tableX (id, c_id,date_column) values (1,1,to_date('2021-09-09 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into tableX (id, c_id,date_column) values (2,1,to_date('2021-03-30 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into tableX (id, c_id,date_column) values (3,2,to_date('2021-09-09 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into tableX (id, c_id,date_column) values (4,2,to_date('2021-03-30 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));

Commit;
```

**Example**

```
using var con = new OracleConnection(conString);
using var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
con.Open();

int myC_id = 2;

var dateAsString = "2021-03-30 09:00:00";
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
var styles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal;

DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(dateAsString, culture, styles);

//DateTime myDate = new DateTime(2021, 3, 30, 9, 0, 0); //2021-03-30 09:00:00

cmd.CommandText = "select id, c_id, date_column from tableX where c_id = :myC_id and date_column > :myDate";

cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":myC_id", OracleDbType.Int32, myC_id, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":myDate", OracleDbType.Date, myDate, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input));

OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Found Row: ID={reader.GetInt32(0)}, C_ID={reader.GetInt32(1)}, DATE_COLUMN={reader.GetDateTime(2)}");
}
```

**Output**

```
Found Row: ID=3, C_ID=2, DATE_COLUMN=09.09.2021 08:00:00
```

You said The `date_column` is type date in the db and your input value `myDate` is a string.
I would recommend converting `myDate` to DateTime in C#. For parsing you have to define a format provider. see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse

Your date string looks like `fr-FR`.

In your example you use the Parameter `:myC_id` in the SQl-Statment and `myC_id` as OracleParameter name. You have to use the same name.

I would recommend the set property `cmd.BindByName = true`. The default is false and parameters are bound by position and not by name. By positions means that the order and amount of `cmd.Parameters.Add()` in your code have to be in the same order of the bind parameters in your SQL-Statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved the problem with a couple of things one day later. Parsing the string date to a DateTime, using the OracleDbType.Date and set BindByName to true.